# How to glue/ laminate a bow (archery)

Tags: glue, laminating

I always wanted to make a bow (archery) the english long bow was a solid bow, not a laminate. Did anybody ever try to glue up a bow that worked afterwards?
If so How pls.

Comment: Seems a little broad and vague to me.  Lots of bows are laminated, I believe most recurves are a laminate, and I've seen longbows too.  of course the lamination stretches the length of the arm, not across it...

Comment: Hello Bowturner   I feel a recurve is a bit ambitious as first project. Thats why I wanted to see what is possible and advisable before I make a fool of myself and i make something that fires backwards

Comment: Well you can laminate a bow.  My point was that the lamination needs to go the length of the limbs of the bow, this will give it its 'flex'

Comment: This requires a _very_ specialized set of techniques that, while adjacent to woodworking, diverges quickly from anything most woodworkers would do. For example, many laminate bows are wrapped in cord to give the joint strength. Did you research elsewhere first, like Youtube or even the Great Outdoors SE? I just don't see much of the knowledge necessary for this being found on a woodworking site.

Comment: @jdv, even some quite complex/intricate laminate bows can be built by any woodworker without *any* prior experience, same as they could make the type of handle asked about in the recent Q on bending and laminating. It's really the making of a solid-wood bow that's particularly specialised by modern standards, given most woodworkers these days aren't used to removing so much waste entirely by hand and make the judgement calls necessary throughout the process that the limbs aren't too weakened. By comparison you only really need to shape the profiles of the limbs on a laminate bow, simple stuff.

Comment: In both cases woodworking techniques can be applied, but the correct application of those techniques is specialized -- this is true for solid wood shaping as it is for laminating and binding. Unless someone here has _actually_ made a laminate bow then general advice on laminates will only get you some part there. I'm saying the typical purview of "woodworking" does not have that x% of specialized information necessary for success.

Comment: @jdv You could make the same argument for making chairs, violins, kumiko, turned objects, etc. I'm not sure what *the typical purview of "woodworking"* means, but woodworking as a field is quite diverse, and I don't think the group is well served by excluding everything beyond tables, cabinets, and other box-like things. Unless there are some actual bow makers here (and there very well might be), we probably can't help the OP build a great bow, but as a group we probably know enough to help him move beyond where he is now.

Comment: Sorry, this argument is silly. Chairs are basic joinery. The single question on caning chairs here was _unanswerable_ though because it is not within the purview of woodworking as the majority of people in the modern era don't do it, and it was historically a specialty technique rarely practiced by the people who actually made chairs anyway. Luthiery is also out of scope for most Q&A here because it is literally a different craft, with a completely separate history. Just because it involves "working" wood doesn't mean it's woodworking.

Comment: More to the point, few of these traditional crafts that happen to use wood and share _some_ tooling have any real overlap with anything most woodworkers would do. This is true if they practice so-called traditional hand woodworking or modern mechanized shop techniques. Not only is bowmaking special, it has always been special. My only argument is that this is just not the forum for this. The OP would be better served elsewhere.

Comment: Welcome to WSE Guido.  Apparently, there is no one with this type of experience.  It does appear to be a very specialized topic and within its subject an answer would be exceedingly broad requiring more of a book chapter than a post here, so I am closing the question.  Good Luck to you, and please return with woodworking related questions related to techniques etc.  You can take the[tour](https://woodworking.stackexchange.com/tour) to learn more about this site.

Answer (score 1):

What will your bow be made from?

PVA can be used in bowmaking to glue wood to wood. If bow will be used outdoors exterior grade of PVA is best.

Obviously PVA not suitable to bond synthetic materials. You will use epoxy if you want to add fibreglass, carbon fibre, micarta etc. But you can also choose this for bows made only from wood. Epoxy has zero creep and 100% waterproof.

[Gluing laminations on a former - How to make a Longbow](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-qdLw79_JUM) uses PVA (Titebond II)
[Making A Laminated Bow In Silence...](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Zhhq0zkSUws) uses epoxy (from Smooth-On, possibly [EA-40](https://www.smooth-on.com/spotlight/bow-makers-depend-ea-40-adhesive/))

Bows made from solid wood still possible today, but much more work!
[Osage orange bow made on this video.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MckLSv_jCHk)
Sweet cherry, [Making a Recurve Bow in Silence](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AJWVtGtF3HA)
Ash, [part 1](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XYPWsZRU2Q4), [part 2](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aPWrkQ8yF90).

Comment: This answer boils down to "here, let me Google that for you", which is probably why the original question got a down vote.

Comment: @FreeMan, yup, but Code of Conduct.

Comment: Sadly, @Graphus, silently following the "CoC" doesn't teach new folk anything.

Comment: thank you Volfram  Really appreciated! And I not even thought of anything but wood. @freeman, I did search the net for how to make a bow(however u right, I do not use google) and did not find what I was looking for.

Comment: @GuidoCoza if you'll take the [tour] or even just hover your mouse button over the up/down vote arrows next to your question, you'll see that research is expected before asking a question and that you're expected to _show_ what research you've done and where you've fallen short.